# Index- match not working

Tags: excel, indexing, match

For the following table how do I Retreive Column C if both Column A and Column B matches 
Column A       Column B      Column C
City 1              City 10          Local
City 2              City 21          Remote
City 3              City 1            Remote
City 4              City 2            Local

I tried using index and match but am getting #N/A

Comment: Pls show how you performed that!

Comment: I mean the #N/A

Comment: In Column D it is some random city to be matched with a city from Column A and in Column E it is some random city to be matched with a city in Column B. In Column F I typed =match(E2,A:A,0) and in Column G I typed =match(F2,B:B,0) but am getting #N/A for both . Though will use Index(C:C,F2,G2)

Comment: Thought* will use

Comment: Sorry If I am confusing. Say in D2 i type a random city name from Column A and in E2 I type a random city name from Column B, then I want to get the Column C value of this combination

Comment: I think you might want to do something like this: http://www.excel-university.com/vlookup-on-two-or-more-criteria-columns/

Comment: I gave each a numeric value and did a sumifs condition

Answer (score 1):

Enter as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=INDEX(C1:C4,MATCH(D2&E2,A1:A4&B1:B4,0),0)
```